# How to determine what is the environment when bootstrap

Tags: extjs, extjs7

What is the config that will determine which environment that it will point to when bootstrapping the app?
It always point to development while when I do sencha app build, it create the production folder in the build folder.

[image]

Comment: when calling `sencha app build` you can pass environment type like production, development, testing.

Comment: hi, thanks, yeah, i know that. but i just wondering when i just use sencha app build without any environment, what is the default? because weirdly, the generated html pointed to development while the code is built into production folder. I wonder is some of my settings wrong.

Comment: running sencha app watch generates development profile, running sencha app build generates production. to access generated production application you should navigate in a browser to `/build/production/{app_name}`, also sometimes maybe your development version will work correctly, but your production build may fail, in that case run `sencha app build testing` and navigate to `/build/testing/{app_name}` to check errors